# I have multiple forms. Login page then data entry and at the end information about entered data

Tags: vb.net

I have multiple forms. Login page then data entry and at the end information about entered data. When I debug the login form pops up after entering credentials data entry form pops up. I want to close the login screen once the data entry screen is open. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you share the code you've written in an attempt to meet this requirement before posting here as a [mre], in accordance with [ask]?

Answer (score 1):

In Project --> XXX Properties, in the Application tab, change the **Shutdown mode** option to **When last form closes**.

Now open your data entry form and close the login form:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim frm As New frmDataEntry
    frm.Show()
    Me.Close() ' close the current form (presumably the "login" one)
End Sub
```